# Создание функции удаления в TO-DO List

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

Люди, помогите разобраться в чем проблема в функции удаления таски. При нажатии на кнопку удаления у меня удаляется другой элемент, не тот, который нужен был. Заранее спасибо.

```
'https://jsfiddle.net/fpqavngo/'
```

Comment: При запросе помощи с отладкой кода, код надо помещать прямо в вопрос, оформив как [repro] (нажимаешь под вопросом "[Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1304927/edit)" для его редактирования, а затем комбинацию клавиш Ctrl+m, и в открывшийся редактор вставляешь как можно меньший кусочек "проблемного" кода: с которым и пример будет работоспособен, и проблема будет воспроизводиться).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, у вас неправильный порядок вставки элементов (cписок узлов создаётся в обратном порядке по сравнению с массивом строк), поэтому всё путается и индексы элементов массива не совпадают с индексами элементов DOM. Попробуйте использовать `.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', ...)` вместо `.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', ...)`.

Comment: Да, всё верно)) Спасибо за разъяснение))